# Using one variable for multiple items data in descriptive programming

Tags: hp-uft

I know that with Descriptive programming you can do something like this:

`Browser("StackOverflow").Page("StackOverflow").Link("text:=Go To Next Page ", "html tag:=A").Click`

But is it possible to create some kind of string so I can assign more than one data value and pass it as single variable? I've tried many combinations using escape characters and I always get error.

For example in the case above, let's say I have more properties in the Page object, so I'd normally have to do something like this:

```
Browser("StackOverflow").Page("name:=StackOverflow", "html id:=PageID")...etc...
```

But I'd like to pass `"name:=StackOverflow", "html id:=PageID"` as a single variable, so when writing many objects I'd only have to write:

```
Browser(BrowserString).Page(PageString).WebEdit("name:=asdfgh")
```

And the first part would remain static, so if the parents' data needs to be modified I'd only have to modify two variables and not all the objects created in all libraries.

Is it possible?

If I was not clear enough please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want to serialise a data structure in that way, would you not be best passing it as JSON or XML?

Comment: To be fair I just want to reduce maintenance, so If I can make it the way I thought i'd only have to change a few lines, because it would be just a few objects. Can xml do that? Could you please give me an example? I never used xml for anything.

Comment: BTW, page's don't really need descriptions https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/10/07/understanding-the-web-test-object-model-in-hp-unified-functional-testing-uft/#Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is UFT's [`Description` object](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.51/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Use_Desc_Obj_4_Prog_Desc.htm)

This allows you finer grained control on the description since in descriptive programming all values are regular expressions but with `Description` you can turn the regular expression functionality off for a specific property.

```vbs
Set desc = Description.Create()
desc("html tag").Value = "A"
desc("innertext").Value = "More information..."
desc("innertext").RegularExpression = False

Browser("Example Domain").Navigate "www.example.com"
Browser("Example Domain").Page("Example Domain").WebElement(desc).Click
```

If you want to represent this with plain string then it's a bit more of a problem, you can write a helper function but I'm not sure I would recommend it.

```vbs
Function Desc(descString)
    Set ret = Description.Create()
    values = Split(descString, "::")
    For Each value In values
        keyVal = Split(value, ":=")
        ret(keyVal(0)).Value = keyVal(1)
    Next
    Set Desc = ret
End Function

' Usage
Browser("StackOverflow").Page("StackOverflow").WebElement(Desc("html tag:=H2::innertext:=some text")).Click
```

Further reading [about descriptive programming](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/11/05/regular-expressions-in-uft/#DescriptiveProgramming).

Comment: Why dont use the "Object Repository"? There you can describe an Element with multiple descriptions and even use regex

Comment: @JonasM. the question was about descriptive programming, I assume there's a reason for that.

Comment: The main reason is because I'm getting too many random reference issues. My web application has random error-behaviors. It's entirely generated with code and has a "native screen back" with an "UC front" and despite sync method, sometimes if still performs actions after sync call. Quite annoying, so with that and other things I decided to "DP" every object. I'll mark your answer as the one since it's the thing I've done, but may I ask your help in this other question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266479/getroproperty-does-not-update-from-objects-passed-from-functions-in-uft

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Motti's excellent answer, you could also `Set` a variable to match your initial descriptive object and then extend it as required:

```
Set myPage = Browser("StackOverflow").Page("name:=StackOverflow", "html id:=PageID")
```

after which you can then use

```
myPage.WebEdit("name:=asdfgh")
```

throughout the rest of the code, so long as the `myPage` object stays in scope...

Comment: This is a good point and for `Page` it's probably fine but you should keep in mind that for other web elements using this variable may cause problems if the page refreshes.  See the description of `RefreshObject` https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/09/20/how-uft-identifies-objects/